# How to display a warning based on selected date

Tags: javascript, jsp, date

In below code I'm trying to display a message based on user selected date.  If the date is greater than 04/26/2014 then the warningAmount should be 50000 if the date is less then 04/26/2014 then the warningAmount should be 25000.  User selected date is coming from the Code 1 and calculation needs to be in Code 2 under else if block. I have tried to do the following but it doesn't work.  Please help!

Code1:

```
<div class="input-section">
                        <p class="label">Shipping Date</p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="sShippingDate" id="sShippingDate" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${claim.clMailingDate}" /> " />  
                        <p class="info" id="shipDateValue">
                            <fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${claim.clMailingDate}" />
```

Code 2

```
_setWarningAmount = function _setWarningAmount(cod, registered) {
        if (cod) {
            _warningAmount = 1000;
        } else if (registered && sShippingDate > 04/26/2014)   {
            _warningAmount = 50000;
        } else if (registered && sShippingDate > 04/26/2014)   {
            _warningAmount = 25000;
        } else {
            _warningAmount = 5000;
        }

        _updateWarningAmount();
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by making the following changes!

```
 _setWarningAmount = function _setWarningAmount(cod, registered, shippingDate) {
        var x = new Date(shippingDate);
        var y = new Date('04/26/2014');

        if (cod) {
            _warningAmount = 1000;
        } else if (registered && x > y)   {
            _warningAmount = 50000;
        } else if (registered && x < y)   {
            _warningAmount = 25000;
        } else {
            _warningAmount = 5000;
        }

        _updateWarningAmount();


    },
```